# Android - applying custom font into textview doesn't work

Tags: android, fonts

I'm trying to sets textview text into a custom font.

In order to do so, I've done the next steps -

1) The layout Xml is looking like so:

```
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_window_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Profile"
                android:textColor="#505A62" />
```

2) I've created a `fonts` folder inside the `assets` folder and place 3 diffrent fonts file. All three of them are a `.ttf` file types. Also the name of each font file and type are written in small letter, like so - `cr.ttf`

3) At the fragment class I've used the next code -

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gd_menu_layout, container, false);

             Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),
                "fonts/cr.ttf");
             titleWindow = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_window_title);
             titleWindow.setTypeface(tf);


             return v;

        }
```

I've tried it with 3 diffrent fonts files but none of them change the textview font.

Any ideas why this code dosen't work?

Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: you may not see any change in the IDE when this code is written , but when you build the app , you will see the font change when you run it in the emulator.

Comment: Well I tried to run it on a real device - couldn't see any change, so that's why I said that this code not working for me

Comment: I've move the font file from the fonts folder to the assets foler, also tried to use the string thing - still not working at all

Comment: if the fonts are in the assets folder , the you don't need to use the string and you don't need to write getActivity().getAssets() in createFromAsset, just write : createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fontname.ttf");

Comment: Well, first of all I do need - getActivity - because it's a fragment. And also I've tried what you said and I've drop the fonts folder from the path - Still not working at all.

Comment: try changing the text on the textView using setText() , to see if you have type casted the textView correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this lib: https://github.com/neopixl/PixlUI

It is fast to try it and see it's magic :)

Answer (score 1):

```
String fontPath = "fonts/cr.ttf";
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), fontPath);
titleWindow.setTypeface(tf);
```

try this

Comment: ckeck whther your folder name and file name are same as u mentioned

Comment: Yes they are, I've checked it twice before I've posted this questoin over here

Comment: have u tried any other font like Face Your Fears.ttf,just testing purpose i am saying because sometym some of font dowsnot work.

Comment: I've tried the Face Your Fears.ttf - and it dosen't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your code bcoz i tried your code with Face Your Fears.ttf,it s working fine,but dont know why it s not working

Answer (score 0):

Set your typeface fonts on all views you are using ,just try my codes...

```
private EditText etComment2;
private TextView tvQuestionText1;
private TextView tvQuestionText2;
private Button btn1; 


     in you onCreate()

    etComment3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etComment3);
    tvQuestionText1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvQuestionText1);
    tvQuestionText2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvQuestionText2);
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
```

create array of your all views here-

```
View allViews[] = 
        {
            etComment2,
            tvQuestionText1,
            tvQuestionText2,
            btn1
        };
```

pass this view object here- 
AppConstant is our class to manage all static methods

```
    AppConstant.setTypeFace(allViews);
```

Now here is our constant class with method TypeFace

```
public static void setTypeFace(View []views)
{

    for(int i=0 ; i<views.length; i++)
    {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(views[i].getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/SourceSansPro-Semibold.ttf");
        if(views[i] instanceof TextView )
        {
            ((TextView)views[i]).setTypeface(tf);
        }
        else if(views[i] instanceof Button )
        {
            ((Button)views[i]).setTypeface(tf);
        }
        else if(views[i] instanceof EditText )
        {
            ((EditText)views[i]).setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Declare styleable in attrs.xml
/res/values/attrs.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="MyTextView">
<attr name="fontName" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>

Create a layout in layout folder

    /res/layout/activity_main.xml
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:customfontdemo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Standard Android Font" />

         <com.authorwjf.customfontdemo.MyTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            customfontdemo:fontName="pipe_dream.ttf"
            android:text="Custom Android Font" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

//Now Create your Custom Textview

/src/MyTextView.java

```
package com.deepak.utilsview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);

    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs!=null) {
             TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyTextView);
             String fontName = a.getString(R.styleable.MyTextView_fontName);
             if (fontName!=null) {
                 Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/"+fontName);
                 setTypeface(myTypeface);
             }
             a.recycle();
        }
    }

}
```

//now see the fonts in your activity after running activity

/src/MainActivity.java
package com.authorwjf.customfontdemo;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```